# Is it Possible to apply AOP features to the beans which are not part of Spring Context?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have an application in which beans are not initialized using the Spring BeanFactory/ApplicationContext.

There are few places where I find that Spring AOP can be useful and I want to apply these AOP features to the beans which are not part of a spring container.

So is it Possible to do so? And if yes, what can use to do the same?

Comment: I guess you can't use Spring AOP, but you can use directly AspectJ

Comment: Which features AspectJ provides (which Spring AOP cant) which will be helpful for me? I am novice to this AOP concept so some pointers would help.

Comment: Well actually if you need to use AOP on beans not managed by Spring you should use all the features of AspectJ...this above all because Spring AOP can't be used on not spring beans. This is a tutorial for aspectj https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting.html